# Will ACTA achieve a site announcement?

Tags: discussion, announcements

Will StackOverflow/StackExchange display a message about [ACTA](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N8Xg_C2YmG0) (IMO 1000x worse than SOPA) as well?

Comment: I though after Jan 18, we were done with the [slacktivism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slacktivism). Silly me...

Comment: "Copy and paste this to other videos" - so clearly you cut and paste this from youtube or suchlike. Not sure what's worse myself, a slacktavist or an someone who spams idiotic chain letters.

Comment: You're going to jail for posting this question, and we're all going to jail for commenting on it.

Comment: Please, for the love of Knuth, not this again. Please, not again.

Comment: @RobMoir Oh, whoops. I didn't notice I'd left that there. (And I can't remember why I'd pasted it there in the first place.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Read the commentary here on "[I hope SOPA passes](http://maddox.xmission.com/)" before you wear the ribbon..

Or the response of the great unwashed prole masses on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/#!/herpderpedia) to the Wikipedia thing.